# My WAMP server can only handle request from localhost

Tags: apache, webserver, wamp

My WAMP server is installed in a virtual machine, and I have developed a simple PHP file and an android file. The android file should be correct and able to send out the HTML request, however the server side PHP program never respond to the request. Therefore I made a simple site in the server and tried to browse it in another desktop, it was not successful. So this seems caused by the configuration of the WAMP server, I myself is only a beginner, that why I choose WAMP server which can allow me to do nearly nothing about the configuration. I have no idea how to fix the problem now, I have already tried to change all the allowance in the httpd.conf file, however it still does not work.

Comment: Does the `Listen` parameter to allow for incoming request from any ipaddress

Comment: The only code in the httpd.conf file related to Listen seems is this part
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80

Comment: Copy that into your question, it's unformatted in comments

Comment: I finally fix it, it is the problem of the virtual machine instead of the server program. I have forgot to set an exception in the firewall, but anyway, thank you for helping